# Creating a keyboard shortcut with python tkinter and get error TypeError: savF() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, function, tkinter, runtime-error, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a tkinter object called `Mwin` I tried to create a shortcut with the command
`Mwin` is the name of my main window that contains all the other tkinter objects I've coded

`Mwin.bind('<Control-s>', saveF)` to open the saveF function which is following

```
def saveF():
    files = [('CSV Files', '*.csv')]
    sFile = asksaveasfile(filetypes = files, mode='w', defaultextension=".dat")
    for i in range(10):
        sFile.write(date[i].get() + "," + timein[i].get() + "," + timeout[i].get() + "," + dHours2in[i].get() + "," + dHours2out[i].get() + '\n')
    sFile.write(dutyTimeinEntry.get() + "," + dutyTimeoutEntry.get())
    sFile.close
```

My application open fine but when I press control s I get the message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: savF() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Is `saveF` an instance method?  Sounds like you need a `self` parameter.  Is `savF` the same as `saveF` (just a typo), or are those two different things?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Functions bound to events will automatically get one parameter that is an object representing the event.

Comment: @CryptoFool saveF isn’t an instance function. It’s just a normal python function that I’m trying to use to respond to pressing control and s to save to a file. From what Bryan Oakley said and a little bit of reading it sounds like I need saveF to have in its definition to accept event as an argument?

Comment: A simple solution, if you don't care about the passed in event, is to modify `saveF()` with either `saveF(_event):` or `saveF(*args):`

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

Snippet code:

```
def saveF(event):
    repr(event.char)
    files = [('CSV Files', '*.csv')]
    sFile = asksaveasfile(filetypes = files, mode='w', defaultextension=".dat")
    for i in range(10):
        sFile.write(date[i].get() + "," + timein[i].get() + "," + timeout[i].get() + "," + dHours2in[i].get() + "," + dHours2out[i].get() + '\n')
    sFile.write(dutyTimeinEntry.get() + "," + dutyTimeoutEntry.get())
    sFile.close

Mwin.bind("<Key>", saveF)
```